# Simulation-based proof in the semi-honest model when a party is corrupted

Tags: provable-security, protocol-analysis

[Full paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-319-18467-8_1.pdf)[image]

Would you mind telling me based on the attached file, why in case 3(corrupted client B), the authors did not use the real input which is $S_B$ and instead they have generated $S'_B$? In this case, I think the reason why authors have generated $S'_A$ is that party B has no access to $S_A$(belongs to party A), but why did they generate $S'_B$, considering that party B has access to $S_B$(the real input)? So, based on this security proof, the input $S_B$ has no role in the process of the simulation by the simulator!

It would be highly appreciated if you could help me with this.